# "Dummy output" and no sound when update to the latest HDA drivers

Tags: 13.04, drivers, sound, updates, hda-intel

My system keeps asking for an HDA drivers update, but everytime I update those drivers to the latest version, sound disappers and only "Dummy output" is available as a choice in the Audio settings panel. Everytime this thing happens, I must re-install an older version of the HDA drivers that actually works, but I really don't understand why I can't update those freakin' drivers! XD
Could you please help me with this issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the newest drivers do not work and there should be no expectation that a driver will work for every different kind of computer with different versions of Ubuntu. Just don't update them. For example, installing/updating the proprietary drivers for my AMD graphics cards always destroys my Unity and other crazy things. It works fine without it, so there is no point in upgrading.

Comment: I understand your point, but that is weird, since they are releasing several new versions for those drivers and the issue is still there...